# Difference between Modulo in Java and VBScript

Tags: java, vbscript, modulo

Is there a difference between the way that the Modulo operates calculates values in Java vs the way that it does in VBScript?

Both of these are returning a digit that I am using as part of a larger number later in the code but I believe the issue is between the way VBScript and Java are handling the Mod operator. I may be wrong though.

I am trying to work through reasons why I am seeing different outputs from when I run the below VBscript code block vs my replicated version in Java, sorry for the delay in updating the post.

The function takes in a String and then works to determine a return digit based upon the logic in the loop. The missing code just has to do with initializing the variables used, and determining the length of the string to loop over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

VBScript:

```
For i=1 to Length

CurrentNumber = Mid(CCNumber,i,1)
CurrentNumber = Int(CurrentNumber)

If (i mod 2) <> 0 then
    ModNumber = CurrentNumber * 2
    If ModNumber > 9 then
        Total = Total + 1 + (ModNumber mod 10)
    Else
        Total = Total + ModNumber
    End If
Else
    Total = Total + CurrentNumber
End If
Next

cd = ((Int(Total/10) + 1) * 10) - Total

if cd = 10 then cd = 0

CheckDigit = cd
```

Java:

```
for (i=0; i<length; i++)
     {
         String currentNumberString = CCNumber.substring(i,i+1);

         currentNumber = Integer.valueOf(currentNumberString);

         if (i % 2 != 0)
         {
             Integer ModNumber = currentNumber * 2;

             if (ModNumber > 9)
             {
                 total = total + 1 + (ModNumber % 10);
             }
             else
             {
                 total = total + ModNumber;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             total = total + currentNumber;
         }

     }

    int cd = ((Integer.valueOf(total/10) + 1) * 10) - total;

    if (cd == 10)
    {
        cd = 0;
    }

    return cd;
 }
```

Comment: Is there reason you believe this to be the case? An example could help people better answer your question.

Comment: Is there some specific issue that you're troubleshooting?

Comment: [Remainder Operator in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) and here is the [Mod Operator in VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basszbdt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)  (I'm assuming unexpected behavior in Negative numbers or Floating points perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One difference: The `Mod` operator in VBScript always returns an integer. Java's `%` operator can return a fractional value. So `5.2 Mod 2` evaluates to 1 in VBScript, but `5.2 % 2` evaluates to 1.2 in Java.

---

Edit: Based on your edit, this appears to be the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). The only real problem with the Java code is a typo; nothing to do with the mod operator. Here you assign a variable `currrentNumber` (with a triple R):

```
currrentNumber = Integer.valueOf(currentNumberString);
```

Then you use a different variable (double R):

```
Integer ModNumber = currentNumber * 2;
```

Edit: Another difference is that because VBScript string indices start at 1, and Java string indices start at 0, the code is using different alternate digits. Either `If (i mod 2) <> 0` should be `If (i mod 2) = 0`, or `if (i % 2 != 0)` should be `if (i % 2 == 0)`, I'm not sure which.

Comment: What would be the easiest way for me to replicate exactly how the Mod operator in VBscript works in Java?

I working on converting a VBscript file into a java class, that is the reason I am asking this question.

Comment: This appears to be a typo from my copy and paste over to this post. In the code I am not seeing that. Thank you for pointing that out here though, and yes you are correct it is the Luhn Algorithm that I am working through.

Comment: That is something that I did notice and I altered the loop starting position for "i" to "0" in an attempt to counteract that. The VBscript is my "true" code that I am working off of so I think that testing altering the if (i % 2 !=0) to if (i % 2 == 0) in the Java would make sense.

Comment: That looks like it did the trick, I cannot thank you enough for your help on this, I have been stuck trying to sort through this issue for a couple days now and it has been solved.